# Is remote_api the only way to execute one-shot script for remote datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need to run a Python script to re-save some entities on remote datastore so that they'll get missing property. Is enabling [remote_api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) the only way to do so or there is something I can enable in remote admin console to allow me run Python scripts from the web interface?

Comment: There's nothing built in to the console, but no one's stopping you from having a handler on the server that `eval`s arbitrary python you type in/upload. See shell.appspot.com for an example (which you can deploy to your own application).

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://shell.appspot.com ?

Comment: Yes. I remember I've seen something like this in admin console, but it seems it was only for local one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all my apps I enable the developer console by default:

```
- url: /devcon/.*
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/admin
  login: admin
```

For Python 2.7 it is:

```
- url: /devcon/.*
  script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application
  login: admin
```

This includes the interactive console which I find great for hacking one-off scripts that need to do something in the actual environment.